# Why isn't this line item StyleCop suppression working?

Tags: stylecop

I have the following, which I gather should disable a stylecop rule on a partiular line of code.

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules",
                 "SA1300:ElementMustBeginWithUpperCaseLetter", 
                 Justification = "External API, no control")]
public void receivedEvent(NV.nConsumeEvent evt)
{
}
```

But it has no effect, the warning keeps showing. What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that SA1300 belongs to NamingRules, not to the DocumentationRules.

So, the correct suppressing would be:

```
[SuppressMessage(
    "Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules",
    "SA1300:ElementMustBeginWithUpperCaseLetter", 
    Justification = "External API, no control")]
public void receivedEvent(NV.nConsumeEvent evt)
{
}
```